# IIS specify outbound IP address for site/handler

Tags: windows, iis

I have a handler deployed on IIS which proxies communication to specific URLs. I need to specify IP address for outbound communication called from this handler different than IP address for general communication from server.
I can isolate those handler to different IIS site if needed.
Currently, I'm redirecting requests for this handler to different server via ARR and URLRewrite, but I'd like to avoid this.
On linux, there is solution to use SRC-NAT rule for specific user, if process was owned by this user (https://serverfault.com/questions/236721/bind-process-or-user-to-specific-ip-linux).

EDIT: If handler was isolated to different site, this site also can be run in different application pool and/or different identity.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you:https://forums.iis.net/t/1183088.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, if I understand correctly, I can choose which IP address will be (or not) used for outgoing traffic with netsh parameter "skipassource". However, I need to exactly join outgoing IP address with specific handler, site or application pool.